# How to debug "Subscript used on non-accessible variable"?

Tags: autoit

This is my code:

```
#RequireAdmin
#Region Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI
#AutoIt3Wrapper_UseX64=n
#EndRegion Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI

ListDrives("REMOVABLE")
ListDrives("FIXED")

Func ListDrives($type)
    $drive = DriveGetDrive($type)

    For $i = 1 To $drive[0]
        MsgBox(64,"",$drive[$i])
    Next

EndFunc
```

The error is :

> ("C:\Users\Javad\Desktop\01.au3" (7) : ==> Subscript used on
> non-accessible variable.:

```
For $i = 1 To $drive[0]
For $i = 1 To $drive^ ERROR)
```

How to debug "Subscript used on non-accessible variable"?

Comment: Seems no removable disk was found (not all removable device declare themselves as "removable"). `DriveGetDrive` gives `@error`=1 when no matching drive was found, so just include `if @error =  then ...` to process only valid arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you drive is not removeable but CD-ROM.
Try this to have a look at your drives.

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

$re = ListDrives($DT_ALL)
_ArrayDisplay($re, 'Drives and Drivetypes')
;~ ListDrives($DT_FIXED)

Func ListDrives($type)
    Local $aArray = DriveGetDrive($type)
    Local $drive_A[0][2]
    If @error Then
        ; An error occurred when retrieving the drives.
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "It appears an error occurred.")
    Else
        For $i = 1 To $aArray[0]
            _ArrayAdd($drive_A, StringUpper($aArray[$i]) & '|' & DriveGetType($aArray[$i]))
        Next
    EndIf
    Return $drive_A
EndFunc   ;==>ListDrives
```